# ReferenceError : window is not defined at object. <anonymous> Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen similar questions that were asked here but none matches my situation. In my web I have 3 `JavaScript` files : `client.js` , `server.js` ,`myModule.js` . In `client.js` I create a window variable called `windowVar` and I add to it some atrributes. In `myModule.js` ,I add some other attributes and use them there and I export the file and require it in `server.js`.

`client.js`:

```
window.windowVar= {
    func1: function(args) {    
       //some sode here
    },
    counter:0
};
```

`myModule.js` :

```
module.exports={wVar:windowVar, addMessage ,getMessages, deleteMessage};

windowVar.serverCounter = 0;
windowVar.arr1=[];
```

`server.js`:

```
var m= require('./myModule');
```

when running the server in node.js I get the following error:

> ReferenceError : window is not defined at object. `<anonymous>`

As I understood window is a browser property ,but how can I solve the error in this case? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, that file seems to be running on the server, not the browser, and there is no `window` on the server? Node does have a `global` object, but why would you use it.

Comment: NodeJS doesn't have a `window` object. So you need to create one `window = window || {}`

Comment: @evolutionxbox where should I create it ?

Comment: @user8244016 why do you need it?

Comment: I'm developing a web-based chat app ,and I need the global var in the module so I can save in it a list of the messages

Comment: @user8244016: *"I need the global var in the module so I can save in it a list of the messages"* No, you don't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder mmm..then how can I update all the users with the new messages?

Comment: @user8244016: Use the object exported from the module. There will only be one of them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder excuse me ,but I don't understand?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`window` is a browser thing that doesn't exist on Node.js, but ES2020 introduced [`globalThis`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-global), which (being part of the JavaScript specification) is available on both compliant browser engines and in Node.js.

If you really want to create a **global** in Node.js, use `globalThis` or (for older versions) `global`:

```
// BUT PLEASE DON'T DO THIS, keep reading
globalThis.windowVar = /*...*/:
// or
global.windowVar = /*...*/;
```

`global` is Node's identifier for the global object (defined in their API before `globalThis` existed), like `window` is on browsers. For code that may run in a wide range of environments, including older ones:

```
const g = typeof globalThis === "object"
    ? globalThis
    : typeof window === "object"
        ? window
        : typeof global === "object"
            ? global
            : null; // Causes an error on the next line
g.windowVar = /*...*/;
```

***But***, there's no need to create truly global variables in Node programs. Instead, just create a module global:

```
let /*or `const`*/ windowVar = /*...*/;
```

...and since you include it in your `exports`, other modules can access the object it refers to as necessary.

Comment: hi , thanks for helping me one more time .. the problem is that I am allowed to use only one global variable

Comment: @user8244016: There's only one global variable above. But I can't imagine why you'd need *any* global variables.

Comment: this is a requirement in my project .. I tried your solution before window but then when adding attribute to it in the module and try to use them then it appears another problem, it seems that the global variable forget about the attributes which were added to it in te module

Comment: @user8244016: *"this is a requirement in my project"* I very much doubt it; and if it is, then this must be for a class, and it won't have come out of nowhere. Review your class notes, etc. In any case, if you actually did the above, it would create a global. So clearly, if it's disappearing, you didn't do the above. I suggest debugging to find out what's wrong.

Comment: do you mean writing `var windowVar = /*...*/;` in the module and then add the attributes ,while still having the window.windowVar in the client.js?

Comment: The reason to have window in node.js is to emulate for scripts that expect to run in a browser.

Comment: I love this comment "// BUT PLEASE DON'T DO THIS, keep reading"

Answer (score 21):

I used something like this and it protects against the error:

```
let foo = null;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  foo = window.localStorage.getItem("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`window` object is present only in the context of browser. When running application on `nodejs` no `window` object is available. If you want to share your variables or functions across multiple files then you have to use `require` and `exports`

client.js

```
module.exports = {
    fun1: function(){

    },
    counter: 0 
}
```

and something like in myModule.js

```
var client = require('./client');
```

Answer (score -1):

For node.js the main window objects is called gloabal. Just use it like this:

```js
const example = {
  some: 'Some',
  another: 'Another',
  theOne: function() {
  
    console.log(this.setTimeOut)
    }.bind(global)
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, when you are using custom-project, and don't need "window" object at all, just define it with blank, before all other contents:

```
window = {};
```