# Instantiate class object with variable class name in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop

Is there a way in nodejs to instantiate class object with variable class name. I am trying the below snippet, it doesn't work though.

```
let className = "hello"; 
let object = new [className]();
```

EDITED
I have multiple classes, out of those multiple classes I will get a subset(Array of String) as Input from another service and I have to call main function of those subset classes.

```
// Multiple classes = ["first", "second", ..............., "twenty"]; 

let subset_class_names = ["first", "three", "five"]; 

for (let aClass of subset_class_names) { 
    let object = new [aClass](); 
    object.main(); 
}
```

Comment: Why? I dont know any usecase for this

Comment: I have multiple classes, out of those multiple classes I will get a subset as Input and I have to call main function of those subset classes.
</br>
`// Multiple classes = ["first", "second", ..............., "twenty"];`

`let subset_class_names = ["first", "three", "five"];

for (let class of subset_class_names) {
 let object = new [class]();
 object.main();
}
`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over class names, why not iterate over the classes itself?

```js
class One {
  constructor(){
    console.log("One constructed");
  }
}


class Two {
  constructor(){
    console.log("Two constructed");
  }
}

const classes = [One, Two];

for(const aClass of classes)
  new aClass();
```

Comment: I will get class names as an input from another service, and then iterate and instantiate the objects.  
This is not possible in my case directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using window

```
var className = 'hello'
var obj = new window[className];
```

Comment: I am getting this error : `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: ok that generally works in client side, since you are using it on node.js look this window is a browser thing that doesn't exist on Node.

If you really want to create a global, use global instead:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964178/referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-at-object-anonymous-node-js

Answer (score 0):

I think most programming problems become easy when you know how to use data structures. In this case all you need is a `Map` of class names to classes themselves.

```js
class One {
  constructor(){
    console.log("One constructed");
  }
}


class Two {
  constructor(){
    console.log("Two constructed");
  }
}

class Three {
  constructor(){
    console.log("Three constructed");
  }
}


const classes = new Map()
classes.set("one", One);
classes.set("two", Two);
classes.set("three", Three);

let subset_class_names = ["one", "two"]; 

for (let aClass of subset_class_names) {
  const theClass = classes.get(aClass);
  if (theClass) new theClass();
}
```