# ReferenceError: window is not defined import react-avatar-edit package

Tags: reactjs

I have just add react-avatar-edit package and just import the package,

```
import Avatar from 'react-avatar-edit';
```

after that i can run yarn start command i was got the **ReferenceError: window is not defined** in react-avatar.js file.please give some idea to solving this issue.
also I have attached screenshot https://prnt.sc/opv5hg

Comment: Is your code `Server side rendering`?

Comment: I just impot the package in my component file

Comment: I know that. I mean are you render react on your server?

Comment: its client side rendering

Comment: After importing package, did you restart your app?

Comment: yes i restart the app but i got the same issue

Comment: Post your package.json file

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964178/referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-at-object-anonymous-node-js

Comment: {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.5",
    "npm": ">=3.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-avatar-edit": "^0.8.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "7.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    
  }
}