# Sublime text 3 doesn't run nodeJS code with its build system

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

I was working with sublime text 3 and running my code with node build system.When I have updated nodeJS to v10, the problems began.

Node Build system :

```
{
"cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe","$file"],
"selector": "source.js"
}
```

The console shows this error:

```
console.log(window);
        ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mhsn67\Documents\Front End NanoDegree\Example\Background-generator\app.js:3:13)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: Looks like the ST build system is using Node under the hood, but your code references `window`, which is part of the [Browser/DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)...

Comment: So it was not producing error before updating to v10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError : window is not defined at object. <anonymous> Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964178/referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-at-object-anonymous-node-js)

Comment: Yes, there is not @VoidSpirit

Comment: @AliLefta because `window` is browser's object not Nodejs'. So if you were not having an error then you were declaring it before then

Comment: I undestand that DOM is not manipulated inside Node.js. but I really confused how it was working :) @VoidSpirit